# Почему не выполняется команда после cmd.exe

Tags: консоль, cmd

Сама команда: `cmd.exe /d D:\Code\main.pyw`
Но выполнение её просто открывает новую консоль, будто ввел просто cmd.exe, на другой же машине все работает корректно, открывается main.pyw, кто знает в чем дело?

Comment: А у вас файлы `*.pyw` ассоциированы с интерпретатором?

Comment: @wchistow, да, можно просто дабл кликом открыть этот файл

Comment: Запускайте через `pythonw.exe D:\Code\main.pyw`

Answer (score 0):

Решил вопрос с помощью `pythonw.exe D:\Code\main.pyw`